# Deleted header file /bits/types.h

Tags: ubuntu, header-file

On compiling a program using `gcc`, I was getting syntax errors in `/sys/types.h`. While investigating the problem, I ended up mixing up the `/bits/types.h` and `/sys/types.h` and I mistakenly deleted `/sys/types.h` as well created some problems in `/sys/types.h`

How do I fix this ?

Are they a part of the `linux-headers` package ?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 x86 with Kernel 3.2.0-36-generic

Comment: The correct package is probably `libc6-dev`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the package name with `dpkg -S /path/to/types.h`,

and re-install it with `apt-get install --reinstall XXX`